# Splunk license - what if licensed amount of data is not used?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a question on Splunk licensing. If I buy a license for e.g. 10 GB/day and if I could not ingest 10 GB per day, is that a license violation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a violation to use less than your license amount.  The licensed amount is a maximum, not a requirement.